# ¿Cómo guardar en una variable el numero de filas de una tabla bootstrap?

Tags: php, bootstrap

Me pueden ayudar de cómo  guardar el numero de filas de una tabla?
la estructura de la tabla bootstrap es el siguiente:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>idArticulo</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $values["product_id"]; ?></td
    <td><?php echo $values["product_name"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <h4>Total de articulos que hay en la tabla: --aqui es donde se pone el total de articulos---</h4>
```

El problema es que cuando inserte 10 productos quiero obtener el total de articulos que hay en la tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasta donde vi, creo ke iteras un arreglo y vas creando las filas en la tabla. Puedes saber la cantidad de elementos con count. Sería algo como esto:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>idArticulo</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <!-- Asumiendo que $arr es un arreglo donde tienes los valores a mostrar en la tabla, lo recorres, elemento por elemento //-->
  <?php foreach($arr as $values) :?>
  <tr>
    <!-- Renderizas el id del elemento actual de la iteración //-->
    <td><?php echo $values["product_id"]; ?></td>
    <!-- Renderizas el nombre del producto del elemento actual de la iteración //-->
    <td><?php echo $values["product_name"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Sales del ciclo foreach //-->
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <!-- Muestras la cantidad de elementos del arreglo //-->
 <h4>Total de articulos que hay en la tabla: <?php echo count($arreglo); </h4>
```

Comment: en el foreach, está de esta manera: foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  {   //pero me marca error al usar el count, es decir al poner:   count $keys    //disculpa no sé mucho de php no se si lo estoy haciendo bien

Comment: No es count($keys) lo que tienes que poner sino count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]) porque el arreglo realmente es ese, lo otro ($key => $values) es para separar en cada iteración la llave y el valor del elemento actual para poder trabajar con ambos durante el ciclo.

Comment: Gracias, funciona!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar `Javascript` para este caso.

Puedes asignarle un ID a la tabla y obtener su etiqueta `tbody` mediante la función `getElementsByTagName`. Tendrás que escoger la posición 0 ya que dicha función devuelve un array y solo tienes un `tbody`. En caso de que no buscaras esta etiqueta te aparecerían también los resultados del `head` como productos de la tabla.

Una vez hecho esto, deberás de obtener todas las filas también por su etiqueta y obtener su `length` (tamaño del array resultante, es decir, número de productos).

Ejemplo:

```js
var filas = document.getElementById("tabla").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = filas + " productos";
```

```html
<table id="tabla">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>idArticulo</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>producto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>producto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>producto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>producto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>producto</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <h4 id="titulo">Total de articulos que hay en la tabla: --aqui es donde se pone el total de articulos---</h4>
```